# Clear contents of multiple input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

Hi I am dynamically adding rows with a button and when I am finished entering information, I would like it to then clear the contents. The button "Add Pokemon" is the one I want to press and it should clear all the contents.

```
function addPokemon() {
    var pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name-container");
    pokemonName.innerHTML = document.getElementById("pokemon-names").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (element[i].value !== "undefined") {
            pokemonArray.push(element[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(pokemonArray);
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemonArray.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("pokemon-container").innerHTML += "<li>" + pokemonArray[i] + "</li>";
    }
    document.getElementById("pokemon-name-container").value = "";
    document.getElementById("move-name").value = "";
}
```

This is my function I am using. ^^

And below is my HTML vv

```
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="pokemon-name-container">
                                <p>Pok&eacutemon Name:</p>
                                <input type="text" id="pokemon-names" size="30">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="moves">Moves:</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="move-container" type="text" id="move-name" placeholder="Enter move here">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="button-container" type="button" id="remove-btn" value="Remove Move" onclick="removeRow()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" class="add-move-button" id="add-move-button" value="Add Move" onclick="addRow()">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" class="add-pokemon-button" id="add-pokemon-button" value="Add Pok&eacute;mon" onclick="addPokemon()">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put to all the inputs you create a unique class that defines them under a parent with a unique id. Then use inside the function of javascript the next pice of code `const childs = document.querySelectorAll('#idParent.classChilds')` this querySelectorAll is kind of like the getElementsById but uses selectors of CSS so it's more powerfull. The querySelectorAll returns you a NodeList of all the elements that matches de DOM with the CSS query.

Then you would only need to do something similar to this using functional programming:

```
const childs = document.querySelectorAll('#idParent .classChilds')
childs.forEach(child=>{
    child.value = ""
})
```

I'm not sure if this code works ***(I'm not with an code editor and a browser to check if there isn't mistakes)***, as I said, you could do something similar to it

HOPE IS HELPFULL

FYI, try to avoid the selectors like getElementById or getElementsByClass....
Try to use this:

```
document.querySelector('CSS SELECTOR')   // GIVES YOU THE FIRST MATCH OF THE CSS SELECTOR
document.querySelectorAll('CSS SELECTOR') // GIVES YOU A NODELIST WITH ALL MATCHES
```

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong. I think you are selecting wrong element "const childs = document.querySelectorAll('#idParent.classChilds')". 
#idParent.classChilds mean it will select element that contain id with idParent and class with classChilds. That's no sense because you use querySelectorAll for an element that is unique already. I think it should be ('#idParent .classChilds')

Comment: Yeah you are right ! I forgot to put an space between the Id and the class, if there is no space, you are right, gonna select the item with that id and this class. nosense, i gonna edit it right now !! THANKS !